# No content in DataTransferManager UI

Tags: c#, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I am using the DataTransferManager in my Win32 Desktop Bridge App to share text and links.
I am using the samplecode from 
[Microsofts Code examples (github)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/ShareSource)
However the share dialog is empty (see image, its says "Try again, Could not show all available methods to share").

[image]

**Loading DataTransferManagerHelper**

```
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
var dtm = DataTransferManagerHelper.GetForWindow(hwnd);
dtm.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
```

**Showing Share UI**

```
IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
DataTransferManagerHelper.ShowShareUIForWindow(hwnd);
```

Comment: I created a desktop bridge and add the the above project to application resource then set as enter point. it works well. Could you tell more detail about your OS version and your app's target version?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the bug.
I was not actually calling the methods

```
DataTransferManagerHelper.GetForWindow(hwnd);
dtm.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
```

Makes sure that these two methods get called otherwise you will get the "no content" share dialog.